# Application Insights alerts for custom requests

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to figure out how I can set up Email/Text alerts for custom requests inside application insights.

I have a number of different custom requests that are uniquely identified by a property in application insights. I can filter on these properties in the Metrics Explorer and even create graphs of the server response time for these specific requests. However I cant figure out how to set an alert if the server response time (for this individual custom request) goes over a certain threshold.

I've tried added a new metric alert rule but the only Metric that is relevant in the drop down in Server Response Time but there appears to be no way to specify this to a specific type of request as identified by a property on the request.

Would anyone know if this is currently possible in application insights and possibly be able to point me in the right direction.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1) Call TrackMetric (provide some metric name) when particular request happens. Then configure alert based on this metric.

2) Write a tool/service/azure function which every few minutes runs a query in Application Insights Analytics and posts result as metric (using TrackMetric). Then configure alert from portal.

Right now AI team is working on providing #2 out of the box.

Comment: Good suggestions, another method I came across was to write a custom query in Application Insights Analytics and return PASSED if this value is within the parameters of my threshold. I can then make this available over a HTTP url and use a availability test to ensure that it passes every 5 minutes..

Comment: Smart! Thank you for sharing it! Definitely will be recommending this as one of workarounds.